# Add existing to-do item to new milestone in Basecamp

Tags: basecamp

How do you add a to-do item in Basecamp to a newly created milestone?

When you create a new to-do list item, there is an option that asks, "Does this list relate to a milestone?"

However, if you edit an existing to-do item, this option is missing.

How can you move a to-do task into a new milestone when the item was created prior to said milestone?

Answer (score 1):

Basecamp has 3 levels of hierarchy: Milestones -> ToDo Lists -> ToDos (though a ToDo List doesn't *necessarily* need to relate to a Milestone).

You can change the Milestone that a ToDo List relates to by Editing the ToDo List and selecting a different Milestone, as follows:

[image: Figure 1]

You can also change the ToDo List that a ToDo belongs to. Under Basecamp's To-Dos tab, hover over a ToDo, and drag the "up/down" handle (see below) in order to drop the ToDo under a different ToDo List. (I believe that both ToDo Lists must be active [not completed] for this drag & drop).

[image: Figure 2]